# There is a length limit to Windows file extensions?

Tags: windows, file-extension

If I want to create a new file extension for a binary/text data file that will open on my own application (extension ".mylongfileextensionname" for example), will Windows list it with my aplication (considering that I already listed it on Windows Registry before)? 
There is a length limit, I mean, on my example should I use ".mylong" or any specific layout?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I always thought 255 total as in Breakthrough's answer but I found this to be contradictory as I started to double-check my thoughts:

```
Windows 2000 has a 254 character limit.
Windows XP has a 255 character limit.
Windows Vista and Windows 7 has a 260 character limit.

Path+Filename limit is 260 characters.
```

http://www.wincert.net/tips/microsoft-windows/windows-7/2427-windows-7-file-transfer-issue-destination-path-too-long.html

Confirmed on this Microsoft site:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/File-names-and-file-name-extensions-frequently-asked-questions
(expand "What is the maximum length of a file name?")

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: fyi: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx .. by using the "other" version of the file api you can use up to 32k chars for the path/filename. by "other" i mean the unicode one which is triggered by using unc paths ala "\\?\"

Answer (score 21):

Besides the fact that any filename [cannot be longer then 255 characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS), there is no limit imposed on a file extension length.  This is because the file's extension is not separate from, but is a part of the filename itself.

While you are free to use any length of extension you wish, I would not recommend using a very lengthy one for one reason: *convention*.  Most file extensions are three to four alphanumeric characters. Anything longer, or with funny characters, is going to "stand out" quite a bit more, be harder to memorize, and *may* be less likely to be adopted (again, it all depends).  For a list of common file extensions, [see this website](http://filext.com/).

Also, note that a file extension is completely arbitrary - it does not directly specify what the contents of a file are, it only *implies* what the contents *should or could be*.